# How to use ajax file upload control inside a repeater

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

My requirement is

1. Should have a option to attach file in each row of a repeater
2. Once I clicked to upload, I have to pass a id and need to execute the insert query

Is there any way to do this using ajax asynchronous?

Comment: Great. And [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)? What difficulties did you encounter when you attempted to achieve this? In fact, what's your question? I am sure you don't expect anyone doing your work, do you?

Answer (score 1):

The IDs of the uploader controls are going to be generated dynamically so you're gonna run into the challenge of identifying which upload control it is that you're trying to get a file from. The way I accomplished this was to use jQuery to find the nearest upload control to the button that was clicked. To "tag" the controls, I assigned a dummy css class that could be selected by jQuery. From there, you can build a JSON object to pass to your service or page method for the processing of your insert operation.

There are other options to handle submitting ALL uploader controls, of course, but you weren't very clear on what you've tried or what the bigger picture here is. You didn't give any specifics in your question, so I'm not giving any specifics for an answer. This is just offering a path to take. Good luck.